# Strange behaviour when drawing a 3D mesh using glDrawElements

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, glsl

So let me explain what code I have written and how the problem arises.

I have made a simple OpenGL application which reads an .obj file and renders it.

I read the file and put the vertex and indices data in two vectors: `std::vector vertices<Vertex>` and `std::vector indices<GLuint>`. Vertex is a struct I constructed:

```
struct Vertex{
    glm::vec3 Position;
    glm::vec3 Normal;
}
```

So now lets suppose I have read an .obj and have filled the above vectors with its data. After that, using the following code I setup my buffers before I render the mesh.

```
void Mesh::setupBuffers()
{
    glGenVertexArrays(1,&VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1,&VBO);
    glGenBuffers(1,&EBO);

    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,vertices.size()*sizeof(MyVertex),&vertices[0],GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,EBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,indices.size()*sizeof(GLuint),&indices[0],GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,sizeof(MyVertex),(GLvoid*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glVertexAttribPointer(1,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,sizeof(MyVertex),(GLvoid*)offsetof(MyVertex,Normal));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

Note that the above code is called only once, namely after I load a new .obj .

Finally to render the mesh I use:

```
void Mesh::Draw()
{
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES,indices.size(),GL_UNSIGNED_INT,0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    GLenum error =  glGetError();
    if(error) std::cout << error << std::endl;
}
```

the Draw function is being called in every render iteration.

**The problem** arises when I have rendered the first model and want to draw another one. Lets say that by pressing button 'a' another model is being loaded (by clearing and filling the same vertices and indices vectors as above), setupBuffer() is being called and the program enters the rendering loop.  **That way the mesh is not being drawn and I get error 1282**

I found out that if I instead call the setupBuffer() in every render iteration,namely:

```
void Mesh::Draw()
{
    setupBuffers();

    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES,indices.size(),GL_UNSIGNED_INT,0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    GLenum error =  glGetError();
    if(error) std::cout << error << std::endl;
}
```

everything works fine and I get no errors.

Obviously this is not the right way to render since the buffers are being generated in every drawing call although the mesh data ( aka vertices,indices) don't change.

Answer (score 0):

Your need generate different VAO VBO and EBO for each mesh.
Something like this

```
calss Mesh{
std::vector<Vertex> vertices;
std::vector<GLuint> indices;
GLuint VAO, VBO, EBO;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I already do that, in fact my Mesh class has exactly these data members. Each time I load a new model a new Mesh object is being created, that has the data members you mention.